# Get selected Row/Columns Count without Setting Selection Mode

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView and I wish to provide a feature of Exporting Selected Rows and Columns to excel

However, My Selected row count was always coming out to be ZERO, so I did

```
 dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

Now, I can not select Individual columns, whenever I select any row, It selects all columns being a full row select

Same is the case with Columns as well
If I do

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullColumnSelect;
```

It selects the whole column.

if I don't do this selection Modes,  then

```
dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count & dataGridView1.SelectedColumns.Count
```

always return zero.

How Can I make something like in the Image ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can get the selected rows:

```
var selectedRows =
    this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
        .Select(cell => cell.OwningRow)
        .Distinct()
        .OrderBy(row => row.Index);
```

You can either call `Count` on that to get the count but, rather than enumerating twice, call `ToArray` and then get the `Length` of the array.

Comment: Thank you @jmcilhinney, This was exactly what I wanted. I didn't knew there exists something like OwningRow or OwningColumn

Comment: How Can I get the Ones which are not selected. I can iterate on all columns one by one and check if they are in this SelectedRow index collection but there has be a faster and easier way of doing that.

Comment: Off the top of my head: `var unselectedRows = this.dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRows>().Except(selectedRows);`

Comment: @jmcilhinney What do you mean by calling `Count`? How would you do it?

Comment: @LV98, the code I provided calls `Cast`, `Select`, `Distinct` and `OrderBy` to get a list of rows in order. If you want just the count of those rows then you simply chain a call to `Count` on the end. If you want the rows and the count, chain a call to `ToArray` instead and that will return an array. You use it like any other array. I shouldn't need to teach you how to call a method.