# Export selected rows AND columns datagridview

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have a datagridview and I need to export only selected rows and columns to pdf using itextsharp. I am able to export whole datagridview and and also only selected rows.

Problem 1. Rows are exported in opposite order, not how I checked them. (e.g I check rows ID 1, 5, 8 and in pdf it is 8, 5, 1)

I do not want to change ***SelectionMode***, because now I use *FullRowSelect* to load values to textboxes and to export selected rows. I found a possible answer here: [Get selected Row/Columns Count without Setting Selection Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23949660/get-selected-row-columns-count-without-setting-selection-mode) but I am not able to use it..

Problem 2. I need user to select rows and also columns to export.

here is my code to export my dgv:

```
private void exportDgvPDF(DataGridView dgvLoadAll, string filename)
   {
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

        iTextSharp.text.Font text = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 11, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);

        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A2.Rotate(), 1, 1, 1, 1);
        PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create));
        doc.Open();

        // I need to remove 21 columns since I have lots invisible "useless" columns .. will work on that later
        PdfPTable pdftable = new PdfPTable(dgvLoadAll.ColumnCount - 21);

        for (int j = 0; j < dgvLoadAll.Columns.Count - 21; j++)
        {
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dgvLoadAll.Columns[j].HeaderText, text));
            cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
            pdftable.AddCell(cell);
        }

        pdftable.HeaderRows = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dgvLoadAll.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
        //for (int i = 0; i < dgvLoadAll.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < dgvLoadAll.Columns.Count - 21; k++)
            {

                if (dgvLoadAll[k, i].Value != null)
                {
                    pdftable.AddCell(new Phrase(dgvLoadAll.SelectedRows[i].Cells[k].Value.ToString(), text));
                    //pdftable.AddCell(new Phrase(dgvLoadAll[k, i].Value.ToString(), text));

                }
            }
        }

        //float[] widths = new float[] { 15f, 50f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f };

       // pdftable.SetWidths(widths);
        doc.Add(pdftable);
        doc.Close(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Here is my complet solution for export selected rows and columns to pdf using itextsharp.

To select which columns will be exported, I use ColumnHeaderMouseClick event. You need to make columns non sortable. I add selected column index to a list columnList. If there is already this index, then it will not be added.

```
         private void dgvLoadAll_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {

        DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn = dgvLoadAll.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];

        if (columnsList.Contains(e.ColumnIndex))
        {
            columnsList.Remove(e.ColumnIndex);
            dataGridViewColumn.HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
        }
        else
        {  
            columnsList.Add(e.ColumnIndex);
            dataGridViewColumn.HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
        }
    }
```

Similar I create a list rowsselected.

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvLoadAll.SelectedRows)
        {
            rowsselected.Add(r.Index);
        }
```

The main export function then:

```
            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            iTextSharp.text.Font text = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 11, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);

            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A2.Rotate(), 1, 1, 1, 1);
            PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create));
            doc.Open();

            // sort selected columns and rows indexes in order to be exported how they are viewed in datagridview
            columnsList.Sort();
            rowsselected.Sort();

            PdfPTable pdftable = new PdfPTable(columnsList.Count);
            foreach (int columnindex in columnsList)
            {
                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dgvLoadAll.Columns[columnindex].HeaderText, text));
                cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
                pdftable.AddCell(cell);
            }

            pdftable.HeaderRows = 0;

            foreach (int rowindex in rowsselected)
            {
                foreach (int columnindex in columnsList)
                {
                    if (dgvLoadAll[columnindex, rowindex].Value != null)
                    {
                        pdftable.AddCell(new Phrase(dgvLoadAll.Rows[rowindex].Cells[columnindex].Value.ToString(), text));
                    }
                }
            }
            //float[] widths = new float[] { 15f, 50f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f };
            // pdftable.SetWidths(widths);
            doc.Add(pdftable);
            doc.Close();
            rowsselected.Clear();
```

You can change the way you select columns e.g. make some checkboxes etc if you need sorting your datagridview columns to be automatic.
SOLVED.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void exportDgvPDF(DataGridView dgvLoadAll, string filename)
{

        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

        iTextSharp.text.Font text = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 11, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);

        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A2.Rotate(), 1, 1, 1, 1);
        PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create));
        doc.Open();

        // I need to remove 21 columns since I have lots invisible "useless" columns .. will work on that later
        PdfPTable pdftable = new PdfPTable(dgvLoadAll.ColumnCount - 21);

        for (int j = 0; j < dgvLoadAll.Columns.Count - 21; j++)
        {
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dgvLoadAll.Columns[j].HeaderText, text));
            cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
            pdftable.AddCell(cell);
        }


        pdftable.HeaderRows = 0;

    // i add foreach i hope this will help you 
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 21; k++)
            {
                if (dgvLoadAll[k, i].Value != null)
                {
                 pdftable.AddCell(new Phrase(row.Cells[k].Value.ToString(), text));
                }
            }

        }


        doc.Add(pdftable);
        doc.Close(); 


        }
```